# Sort with COALESCE in elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have issue on sorting null column with ElasticSearch. Previously I'm using sql query `COALESCE` to get non-null value from column. How can I sort non-null value from columns?

**SQL Query**

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(
  NULLIF(table1.colA,''),
  NULLIF(table1.colB,''),
  NULLIF(table1.colC,'')
) DESC
```

The above statement will check if colA has value, then pick colA. If colA is null, it will check colB.

How do I sort with `COALESCE` similar function in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [script based scoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) with this feature you have full control over how the  `_score` field is calculated.

In your case you could write a small painless script that returns the first non empty field in the document.